# Snakemake: Building DAG of jobs... Nothing to be done

Tags: r, workflow, snakemake

Upon snakemake
I am getting

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done.
```

and if I try

```
snakemake -n dag
```

I get

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce dag (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

My main snake file:

```
configfile: "config_rules/config.yaml"

include : "config_rules/wholeblood.smk"
```

wholeblood.smk file:

```
# GLOBAL
g_blood = "whole"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/ttest_{suffix}_whole.fthr", suffix = config['suffix'])

rule wb_statstests:
    input:
        eset = "data/PAXgene/samples.all_genes.iqr/{}".format(config['whole'][0]),
        pattern_files = expand("data/GE_pattern_genes/{p_file}", p_file = config["pattern_files"])
    output:
        "results/ttest_{suffix}_whole.fthr"
    script:
        "scripts/stat_tests.R"
```

Comment: I would try moving `rule all` to main Snakefile. Unlike [`subworkflow`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#sub-workflows), I don't think `include` modular file can have their own `rule all`.

Answer (score 2):

"Nothing to be done." indicates that all the files needed by the `all` rule already exist. Maybe `config["suffix"]` is empty?

`snakemake -n dag` tries to calculate the graph of the rules that should be executed in order to satisfy a rule named "dag" or produce a file with that name.

If what you want is a graphical representation of the rules to be executed you need the `--dag` option, and you need to pass its output to the `dot` command in order to produce a picture:

```
snakemake --dag | dot -Tpdf > dag.pdf
```

(`-n` is not needed when creating the graphical representation)